# Redis время хранения

Tags: php, redis, nosql, база-данных

Здравствуйте, как можно установить время хранения для хеш таблицы Redis.
`$redis->hset('Ключ', 'Значение 1','Значение 2'))`, а именно для этого ключа и Значения 1, используя php.

Comment: Какую библиотеку используете для взаимодействия с Redis?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете библиотеку phpredis, тогда для установки времени жизни ключа можно воспользоваться методом `setEx()`, вторым параметром которого можно передать количество секунд, которые ключ должен жить:

```
$redis->setEx('ключ', 3600, 'значение 1');
```

Как вариант, можно установить значение, а время жизни ключа установить отдельной командой `setTimeout()`

```
$redis->hset('Ключ', 'Значение 1','Значение 2'));
$redis->setTimeout('Ключ', 3600);
```

Comment: Отлично работает для set, но не работает для hset.

Comment: @МихаилЛобанов а если явно выставить время жизни при помощи метода `setTimeout()` тоже не срабатывает?

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример, а то я не совсем понял.

Comment: @МихаилЛобанов поправил ответ, привел пример с `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Не работает, setTimeout.

Comment: Все разобрался, я использую другую библиотеку. predis, а мне нужен phpredis, наверное.